# A condition for Artinian topological spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

A topological space $X$ is called Artinian if the descending chain condition holds for open subsets of $X$. If the descending chain condition holds for open basis subsets of a Hausdorff space $X$ with the property that the intersection of two open basis is an open basis, can we prove that $X$ is Artinian?

Also, is there any proof for the fact that every Artinian Hausdorff space is finite?

Comment: Answer: NO. Any infinite discrete space provides a counterexample. (It's also a counterexample for Noetherian case).

Comment: It'd be nice if you mentioned your editing (some Qs on MO fail mentioning their editing, thus making some answers look silly for no good reason).

Comment: Your editing didn't help. The infinite discrete space is still a counterexample.

Comment: @WlodAA an infinite discrete space is neither artinian nor noetherian, so I don't know what you claim to provide a counterexample.

Comment: Actually the answer is yes (before unnecessary edits) and is an exercise. The original question was whether every artinian Hausdorff space is finite. Indeed, for $x\in X$, the artinian property implies that there is some minimal open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ (possibly not unique), and the Hausdorff property forces $V=\{x\}$. So $X$ is discrete, and discrete artinian clearly implies finite.

Comment: @YCor As far as I can tell from the edit history, the question whether every artinian Hausdorff space is finite was not the original question but was introduced in version 3. The original question was whether the descending chain condition (DCC) for a basis implies DCC for the whole topology, and this is what WlodAA answered negatively, the counterexample being an infinite discrete space, which is (as you noted) not artinian but has a basis, the family of singletons (and $\varnothing$ to make it closed under intersection), with DCC.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thanks. anyway all interpretations makes it non-research level. Also you're right, T1 is enough for my argument (which is repeated in Henno's answer)

Comment: @YCor, "an infinite discrete space is neither artinian nor noetherian"--exactly! and that's half of the reason why any infinite discrete space is a counterexample. The other half of the argument is that the base consisting of the 1-element sets, together with the empty set is artinian and noetherian.

Comment: @WlodAA ok. Actually the formulation doesn't make it clear it means for some or for every basis. In any case, both interpretations make the question off-topic.

Comment: @YCor, for every basis, it would mean for the topology itself too. This would amount to a trivial tautological TRUE, i.e. such interpretation would make no sense.

Comment: @WlodAA yes I know, but given that the other interpretation is also trivial... no need to lose more time discussing this.

Comment: In general, OM is kind of funny. Anyway, as @AndreasBlass has mentioned, every Artinian $T_1$-space is finite: if $T_1$-space X is infinite, where $\ x_1\ x_2\ \ldots\ \in X\ $ are all different, then open subsets $\ X\setminus\{x_1\ \ldots\ x_n\}\ $ form a decreasing sequence. QED. Also, a clearly nicer and general result holds too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is Artinian, then for every $x \in X$ there is a minimal neighbourhood $U_x$ such that if $O$ is open with $x \in O$, then $U_x \subseteq O$.

This is a simple application of Zorn's lemma on the poset of open neighbourhoods of $x$, ordered by reverse inclusion. The Artianness of $X$ implies that all chains in this poset are finite and then the intersection is an upperbound. So a maximal element exists. If $O$ is then open and contains $x$, we have $O \cap U_x \ge U_x$ so that by minimality $O \cap U_x = U_x$ or $U_x \subseteq O$.

If $X$ is moreover Hausdorff or even $T_1$, for $x \in X$ we have that $U_x  =\{x\}$ or otherwise $y \neq x$ with $y \in U_x$ would exist. But $x$ must have a neighbourhood missing $y$ and this contradicts $y \in U_x$. So $X$ is discrete. And a discrete space is Artinian iff it is finite.

Comment: Unless I overlooked something, the same proof works with $T_1$ in place of "Hausdorff".

Comment: The QUESTION asks: can we prove that X is Artinian? But your answers ASSUMES that $X$ is Artinian. I don't see any logical relation between your answer and the Question.

Comment: @WlodAA the last line asked “is there any proof that an Artinian Hausdorff space is finite?”

Comment: @AndreasBlass I agree. The question asked for Hausdorff. But indeed such a space can at best be $T_0$ I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma by "such a space" I guess you mean "a infinite artinian topological space". Sure there are $T_0$ examples and no $T_1$ example.

Comment: @YCor, I have a full result (properly formulated, of course) for all topological spaces (i.e. topologies--never mind points) and more.